# Powerdns Subdomain & Delegation

Tags: dns, delegates, subdomain, powerdns

I'm using PowerDNS authoritative server and pdns-mysql-backend.
    And I 'm trying to create a subdomain and delegate the external NS to it.
    But I can't find a proper doc or example for it. I just need to create NS records for subdomain?

```
1. existing domain is "example.com"
2. sub-domain that I want to create is "test.example.com"
3. external NS is "ns1.book.com"

and I have created records to mysql like below.

"domains table"
id |name             |master  |last_check | type  |notified_serial | account
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |example.com      |(NULL)  |(NULL)     |MASTER |               0|(NULL) 
2  |test.example.com |(NULL)  |(NULL)     |MASTER |               0|(NULL)

"records table"
id |domain_id |name             |type  |content  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |         1|example.com      |SOA   |ns1.example.com hostmaster.example.com 10 900 600 86400 3600 
2  |         1|example.com      |NS    |ns1.example.com
3  |         1|example.com      |NS    |ns2.example.com
4  |         1|ns1.example.com  |A     |10.10.10.10
5  |         1|ns2.example.com  |A     |20.20.20.20
6  |         1|test.example.com |NS    |ns1.book.com 

Is there anything I have to do?
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In most cases when using MySQL Backend you will most probably want to use the type "NATIVE" for your zones
2. Remove the "test.example.com" zone
3. The record is correct and will work

Comment: Nah, he wants test.example.com use ns1.book.com